# System of ODEs with intial values

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The system of ODE 
$$ \begin{equation}
\frac{dx}{dt}=(1+x^2)y;  t\in\mathbb{R}\\
\frac{dy}{dt}=-(1+x^2)x;  t\in\mathbb{R}\\
(x(0),y(0))=(a,b)
\end{equation}$$ has a solution:

(a) only  if $(a,b)=(0,0)$

(b) for any $(a,b) \in\mathbb{R} \times\mathbb{R} $

(c) such that $x^2(t)+y^2(t)=a^2+b^2$ for all $t \in\mathbb{R}$

(d) such that $x^2(t)+y^2(t) \rightarrow \infty $ as $t\rightarrow \infty $ if $a>0$ and $b>0$

Comment: Well  not all of these statements can be true.

Comment: not all but some of 'em are bound to be true. Need to know who are true.

Comment: Then please say so and tell us what you have done so far. This is not a homework solving service.

Comment: I am sorry, Prof. Engler. I tried the rule by Picard for solving simultaneous differential equations with initial conditions, and arrived at two iterations for both $x$ and $y$, which were indicating the option d. But it is answered to be wrong. I am sure about options a and b. I believe you could help me in the cases of option c and d

Answer (score 1):

Define the Lyapunov function $V(t)=x^2(t)+y^2(t)$ and note $V(0)=a^2+b^2$. Compute the derivative of $V$ along the trajectories of your system: $\dot{V}(t) = 2(x(t)\dot x(t) + y(t) \dot y(t)) \equiv 0$. It gives you the answer (c) or (d). To choose (a) vs (b) check the continuity of the r.h.s of the ODE.